# Does Renderscript use memory of the heap, or like JNI?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, heap-memory, renderscript

As the title says.

Suppose the max heap size is 50MB , yet the device has 2GB of RAM, will Renderscript be able to use the 2GB or will it be constrained to the 50MB ?

If it will be constrained to the 50MB , is it possible to use the 2GB instead somehow?

If it won't be constrained to the 50MB , how do I use it this way?

And, does the "Allocation" usage actually allocate more memory, or is it more of binding of the data of the bitmap to be used on Renderscript ?

I'm asking this because sometimes you'd want to use a lot of memory to handle a task, even though the input and the output might be small in memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

In my experiments, renderscript allocations were on the budget of Java heap. This is not said explicitly in the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/guide/topics/renderscript/advanced.html#allocating-mem), but can be deduced from words:

> the Android VM can carry out garbage collection as well as share memory with the RenderScript runtime layer

I am not sure if this applies to static (compile-time) allocations as well.

Comment: What do you mean by the "static allocations" ? You mean those that are inside the RS code itself ? like "int [1024]" etc... ?

Comment: I mean *Non-static, global variables that you declare in your RenderScript are allocated memory at compile time. You can work with these variables directly in your RenderScript code without having to allocate memory for them at the Android framework level.*

Comment: Thing is, are those variables a part of the heap, or are they like on JNI, a part of the device's RAM ?